# Getting iCloud status information from MPMediaItems

Tags: objective-c, nsurl, icloud, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaitem

```
NSURL *assetURL = [mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];    
NSNumber *percent = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
[assetURL getResourceValue:&percent forKey:NSURLUbiquitousItemPercentDownloadedKey error:&error];
return [percent unsignedIntValue];
```

In this block of code, both 'percent' and 'error' are nil after calling getResouceValue:forKey:error:

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your `MPMediaItem`, it may not even have a valid `MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL` -- any DRM'd media (such as older DRM'd .m4p music files, or DRM'd "TV Show" videos from iTunes) from the "iPod Library" does not have an AssetURL defined.

Beyond that, I don't have much experience with the iCloud stuff yet other than to ask if you're certain it's even possible to view this kind of information on `MPMediaItem`s since they don't technically live within your App's sandbox?

Also, did you setup your App's iCloud entitlements?
[Apple Doc: Configuring Your App’s iCloud Entitlements](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW3)

Comment: I'm not certain it's possible no, but I can't find much in the documentation about working with MPMediaItems in the cloud, other than the fact that you can trigger a download by telling the MPMusicPlayerController to play them.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help. I guess I'd suggest first verifying you're getting a non-nil *assetURL from your first line of code.

Comment: Added edit to some Apple documentation on iCloud entitlements

Comment: Thanks for the help. After playing with it, it turns out the assetURL is nil if the item is in the cloud or while downloading, then non-nil after its been fully downloaded.